# Is it possible for two people work on the same Indesign document at the same time?

Tags: adobe-indesign

Is it possible for two people work on the same Indesign document?

Answer (score 4):

This depends on what you mean.

- You can have multiple people work on a [Book](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/creating-book-files.html) each working on separate sections.
- You can also have multiple people now work on copy using [InCopy](http://www.adobe.com/products/incopy.html?mv=product&mv2=accc#).
- You can NOT have multiple people working on the same part of a book file, which is a good thing. It would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately InDesign has no realtime collaborative working feature.

If you need to work in a magazine or something like this that usually sports several people working at the same product, things you can do are:

- Split up your work into multiple INDD files, eg. one file per story.
  Then merge the individual files into an InDesign book.
- And now in CC we got InCopy, in which you edit stories without actually having to open the InDesign files.

Comment: InCopy is not new :) It has been around since 2003 - albeit as a separate product.