# Multiple designers working on indesign file

Tags: adobe-indesign

We have several (remote) designers working on the same inDesign file.  What kind of check-in/check-out file management options are available so that they don't overwrite each other and each has access to the newest version of the file?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Miriam, welcome to Graphic Design Stack Exchange. Your question has already been asked and answered over here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/79026/is-it-possible-for-two-people-work-on-the-same-indesign-document-at-the-same-tim/79027 It is not possible to let two users open an InDesign document at the same time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible for two people work on the same Indesign document at the same time?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/79026/is-it-possible-for-two-people-work-on-the-same-indesign-document-at-the-same-tim)

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any check-in/check-out options in InDesign itself.
I would recommend looking into InCopy (which is part of the Creative Suite package) -- I believe that tool is designed to allow multiple people to work on sections of a single InDesign file at one time.

Comment: Thank you.  I looked into it but as far as I could tell, it only dealt with copy/content areas.  We're dealing more with design elements/layout.  Or can incopy handle design too?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used it myself, so I can't really answer your question.  You might want to go to www.indesignsecrets.com, and type InCopy in the search bar and see what they have to say about it.  One of the people who runs the site is a big InCopy user and so there may be more detailed information there that you can read.